# How can I select records with two constraints on the same association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, roles

I want to be able to select users who have multiple roles:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I know how to select users with either of two roles:

```
User.joins(:roles).where(roles: { name: [:admin, :manager] })
```

But how do I find all users who have at least :admin AND :manager roles?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

```
User.select("DISTINCT users.*").
  joins("JOIN users_roles a ON a.user_id = users.id").
  joins("JOIN roles b ON b.id = a.role_id").
  joins("JOIN users_roles c ON c.user_id = users.id").
  joins("JOIN roles d ON d.id = c.role_id").
  where("b.name = ? and d.name = ? ", :admin, :manager)
```

Comment: This will return an `OR` not an `AND`.

Comment: I believe this will search for users with the manager role only, not both (it drops the first one). Try applying `to_sql` to it and check the result.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. When running this, the sql generated is `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "users_roles"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'manager'`. shioyama is correct.

Comment: I have updated the answer. My last attempt didn't work as a hash can't have duplicate keys (rightly so).

Comment: That doesn't work either, I'm afraid. This will rows where the name is both admin and manager simultaneously i.e. it will always return 0 rows.

Comment: @Rupert, the problem statement `:admin AND :manager roles` is ambiguous. Can you expand your question?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
users = User.joins(:roles)
users.where("roles.name" => "admin") & users.where("roles.name" => "manager")
```

Note that this produces two SQL load queries, which I think may be inevitable for this type of search. (Your alternative solution also makes two SQL queries.) Also note that it returns an array rather than an activerecord relation, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works but feels wrong:

```
Role.where(name: :admin).first.users.joins(:roles).where(roles: { name: :manager } )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the association as `has_many :through`, you can count the unique roles by user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end

# Note: add an id column on the join table
class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles
end


User.joins(:user_roles => :role).
  select("users.*, COUNT(DISTINCT user_roles.id) as user_role_count").
  where("roles.name IN ('Admin','Manager')").
  group("users.id").
  having("user_role_count = 2")
```